# Child form's controls not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mdi, form-control

I am using an MDI form in which I have given option tool strip menu item as a call to a new child form. On the child form I have some buttons and DataGridView. But when I click the child form option the buttons and DataGridView are not displaying correctly. Provided I have already set the isMdiContainer property to true of MDI form.

The scenario runs successfully when I simply show a form, but the problem occurs when I use the form as a child form. Here is the code which I wrote in a tool strip menu item click:

```
frm_bank_master myfrm = new frm_bank_master();
myfrm.MdiParent =this;
myfrm.Show();
```

Comment: are you sure you need MDI here ? mdi is for integrated multiple windows like photoshop or old style applications like that. maybe you just need a child dialog here, modal or not depending on your needs.

Comment: Always include a tag from the primary language you're working with. I infer that this is C# and tagged it as such. If that is not the case, then please change it to the correct tag.

Comment: yes I need mdi form.and thanx.for editing.